# Bigquery - Resources exceeded during query execution while creating bins from 10M table using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with roughly 10M records, where each record is an ID and some probability (ranges between 0 and 1).
All the IDs are unique. I am trying to break this 10M dataset into 1,000 bins - meaning each bin will have 10k records in it.
But I want to compute these bins based on the probability and hence I arrange the table first in descending order of the probability
and then I try to create the bins.

```
--10M dataset
with predictions as
(
select id ,probability
from table
)

-- give a rom_number to each record and then create 1000 groups
, bin_groups as (
select
id,
ceiling(1000.0*ROW_NUMBER() over(order by probability desc) / (select count(distinct id) from predictions)) as bins
from predictions
)

select *
from bin_groups 
where bins = 1 
limit 100
```

However, I get below error while executing this query -

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 102% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): JOIN operations: 96% other/unattributed: 4%
```

I read here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output#use_a_limit_clause_with_large_sorts  that we need to limit the results while querying but seems like LIMIT is not functioning either.

Comment: Try putting the `where bins = 1 ` or your `limit` inside the inner select and not at the last step to reduce resource needed to calculate the over function.

Answer (score 1):

The limit that you have happens after the materializing the 2 select statements above so adding the limit outside won't work.You may have to put the limit inside the bin_groups, although I'm not sure if it would still fit your use-case.

```
--10M dataset
with predictions as
(
select id ,probability
from table
)

-- give a rom_number to each record and then create 1000 groups
, bin_groups as (
select
id,
ceiling(1000.0*ROW_NUMBER() over(order by probability desc) / (select count(distinct 
id) from predictions)) as bins
from predictions
limit 100
)

select *
from bin_groups 
where bins = 1
```